# iOS - Table cells not being redrawn on device rotation

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

So I have an application which I'm trying to optimize for all the orientations. But I'm having a problem with table views and autorotation. This is how it looks when in Portrait:

[image: Portrait]

Now, when I rotate the device, it looks like this:

[image: Landscape bad]

But as SOON as I touch the table it fixes itself and looks like this:

[image: Landscape good]

So, how can I make it happen automatically when the view is rotated and not wait for the user to tap on the table? Thanks!

I tried with the following code with no success:

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) fromInterfaceOrientation {    
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with the *data* of the table. And look at how the whole right side of the table is missing. The cells *are* getting wider - otherwise we would see the red buttons. It looks like either the UITableView itself or something *else* on the screen has the wrong subview-layout behavior. Do you have subview layout code? Autoresizing? Constraints? What?

Comment: Good call! I had a mask that I was not resizing automatically. See the fade at the end? That is what I was using the mask for... Should I delete the question? Answer my own question? Or what?

Comment: I had to think hard about what to do here! Here's my opinion: first, solve the mask resizing problem. A mask is a *layer* not a view, so you don't get automatic resizing; this is actually quite a difficult issue to deal with. Then yes, answer your own question - because it's a serious issue with masks and other sublayers.

Comment: faced same problem, strange, that when shadow gradient was lying in it's own view, not in cell's content view, it's stretched by autolayout, when added to cell's content view - not. Second case solved with setting shadowFrame in layoutSubviews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this gives exactly the same look as you have (I can't really tell from your pictures). The cells fade into black at the bottom of the table. This code is in a UIViewController, with a table view added as a subview. The table view was given a blue background color. This worked perfectly on rotation.

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    self.maskGradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.maskGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    self.maskGradient.frame = self.view.bounds;
    self.maskGradient.colors = @[(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1] CGColor],(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1] CGColor],(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:.2] CGColor]];
    self.maskGradient.locations = @[@0.0f,@0.9f,@1.00f];
    self.view.layer.mask = self.maskGradient;

    // other code to populate the table
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Comment: Don't forget [super viewWillLayoutSubviews]

Comment: @JVC There's no need to call super, because the default implementation does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was not with the table, but with a mask layer I was using. It looks like CALayers don't support autoresizing, so I'm using the following code:

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) fromInterfaceOrientation {    
    maskLayer.frame = self.maskView.bounds;
}
```

It doesn't animate while rotating. It finishes rotating, and THEN animates the mask. It's weird, but it works for me. Should anyone have a better solution, I'll remove my answer and give it to someone else.

Comment: Try using `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` instead, and use Core Animation to match the duration.

Comment: Yes! If you make it into an answer I can choose it!

Comment: You can just implement: -(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    self.maskLayer.frame = self.maskView.bounds;
}  This worked for me with no problem with animation.

Comment: Yes, do try what @rdelmar said.

Comment: It actually gave me the same results as doing -(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{
 maskLayer.frame = self.maskView.bounds;
} 
Whoever makes the proper answer, gets to be chosen

Comment: Maybe we're making our layers differently. I used a UIView controller with a table view added. I gave the table view a blue background color and the cells a clear background color. I then set the mask of self.view.layer to a gradient layer.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
     return YES;

    //return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

return yes is needed of autorotaion .